# How to upload app with multiple targets with same Bundle ID

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, ios-targets

#### Context:

I have a published app on the AppStore, exclusively available for iPhone. Now, I want to extend its compatibility to iPad by creating a version specifically tailored for the iPad. However, due to significant design differences between the two versions, I'm considering creating a new target with the destination set to iPad. I am uncertain about how this setup will function.

#### Issue:

In Xcode, it's possible to create one target for iPhone and another for iPad, both sharing the same Bundle ID. However, in AppStore Connect, iPhone and iPad versions are combined. When exactly during the installation process will the transition between iPhone and iPad versions occur? Alternatively, would it be more feasible to have a single target and dynamically determine the device during the app launch process (`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`) based on `UserInterfaceIdiom`, subsequently initiating the appropriate coordinator/screens/viewmodels?

How can I upload an app with two targets, sharing the same bundle ID but with different destinations (iPhone and iPad) to AppStore Connect?

If you have any ideas or suggestions for better approaches to accomplish this task, I would appreciate it if you could share them in your response.

I intend to develop a distinct iPad version of the application while retaining shared resources such as UI components, network, and storage layers with the iPhone version.

How can I ensure that iPad users can exclusively access the iPad version of the app? Would it be preferable to achieve this through separate targets or by utilizing the UserInterfaceIdiom?

Comment: You can either release a seperate app for iPad or you can detect the device type at launch and prevent the relevant UI. You can't have two targets in the one bundle with the same bundle id.

Comment: @Paulw11
You can definitely have multiple targets with same bundle. Try before speaking.

Comment: @Victor ... keep in mind that a user ***might*** be utilizing multi-tasking on an iPad (split-view, slide-over, etc), in which case checking for the `UserInterfaceIdiom` will likely not give you the results you want. Better to develop an adaptive UI